# How to use logspace() in numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying to generate the value between given range i.e. values from  10^-1  up to  10^−14 and I'm getting a wrong output

I have implemented the logic to understand this logspace, but couldn't figure it out.

```
import numpy as np

delta = np.logspace(1, 14, dtype=np.float64)
print(delta)
```

Expected output is :

```
>>> print(delta)
[  1.00000000e-01   1.00000000e-02   1.00000000e-03   1.00000000e-04
   1.00000000e-05   1.00000000e-06   1.00000000e-07   1.00000000e-08
   1.00000000e-09   1.00000000e-10   1.00000000e-11   1.00000000e-12
   1.00000000e-13   1.00000000e-14]
```

Comment: Read the docs? `np.logspace(1, 14, 14)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html):

> In linear space, the sequence starts at base ** start (base to the power of start) and ends with base ** stop.

So `np.logspace(-1, -14, 14)` gives:

```
array([1.e-01, 1.e-02, 1.e-03, 1.e-04, 1.e-05, 1.e-06, 1.e-07, 1.e-08,
   1.e-09, 1.e-10, 1.e-11, 1.e-12, 1.e-13, 1.e-14])
```

Or with more "precision" (as asked in the comment):

```
np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(float='{:10.8e}'.format))
np.logspace(-1, -14, 14)
```

Gives:

```
[1.00000000e-01 1.00000000e-02 1.00000000e-03 1.00000000e-04
 1.00000000e-05 1.00000000e-06 1.00000000e-07 1.00000000e-08
 1.00000000e-09 1.00000000e-10 1.00000000e-11 1.00000000e-12
 1.00000000e-13 1.00000000e-14]
```

Note: this changes every numpy array with floats that you print afterwards..!

Comment: how can I show the decimal precision? Like expected output in question?

Comment: You can control that with `np.set_printoptions()`, e.g. `np.set_printoptions(formatter=dict(float='{:10.8e}'.format))`. Then the result is `1.00000000e-01 1.00000000e-02 1.00000000e-03 ...`.

Comment: I was using the set_precisions() and thank you for your help.